# Adding <li> to an existing <ul>

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `MultiSelectList` in View.

```
@Html.ListBox("AreaList",new MultiSelectList(new List<State>()),
    new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "انتخاب منطقه...", style = "width: 90%;", tabindex = "4" }
)}
```

```html
<div id="AreaList_chosen" title="" style="width: 994px;" class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active">
    <ul class="chosen-choices">
        <li class="search-field">
            <input tabindex="4" value="انتخاب منطقه..." class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 89px;" type="text">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add `li` to `ul.chosen-results` in jQuery. I use this code but it doesn't append items.

```
var li = $('<li></li>');
li.html('Test!');

$("#AreaList_chosen > div.chosen-drop ul").append(li);
$(".chosen-results").append(li);
```

Comment: There is no reason the code you shown here would not work. Have you checked the console for errors elsewhere in your code?

Comment: I use javascript debuger, but i don't have any error but don't add item.

Comment: What event are you running your code under? Is the `#AreaList_chosen` or any child elements added to the page after it has loaded?

Comment: No, i have a dropdownlist, that add this code in `dropdownlist.change()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an option to the select that the `chosen` plugin is applied to

```
$('#AreaList').append($('<option></option>').text('Test!').val(''));
```

and then trigger the updated event

```
 $('#AreaList').trigger('chosen:updated');
```